# Your Outline Server was installed correctly, but we are not able to connect to it

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables, firewall

I'm trying to config `Outline VPN` and
I bought a `Droplet` from `Digitalocean` with **`Ubuntu 22`**.

So, my server generated URI string correctly:

```
CONGRATULATIONS! Your Outline server is up and running.

To manage your Outline server, please copy the following line (including curly
brackets) into Step 2 of the Outline Manager interface:

{"apiUrl":"https://***.***.***.***:41591/nBGhsdKbtPJL35f8LfA","certSha256":"ABCSDED8BF654ABDD9FD46DB936D122FDDE7B4815SDDA2757B5133C1A74E7"}
```

in addition, script says:

```
Make sure to open the following ports on your firewall, router or cloud provider:
- Management port 41591, for TCP
- Access key port 28592, for TCP and UDP
```

This is my `iptables -L` result:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1gb-nyc1-01:/etc/init.d# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:41591
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:41591
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:28592
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:28592
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpts:1024:65535
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:1024:65535

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
```

And `ufw`:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1gb-nyc1-01:/etc/init.d# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

As I have a `digitalocean Droplet`, this is my firewall config on digital ocean panel:

[image]

[image]

And finally, when I check my pot and IP, I give this result:

[image]

This is my outline manager report:

[image]

> Does anyone know what is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: You are trying to access a Ubuntu Core 22 machine? Are you sure that is what the OS is?

Comment: @David yes, I am